# The usage of prepositions “about, with, at” after the adjectives expressing irritation, touchiness

Tags: prepositions

Are there any firm rules of how to pick out the right preposition to use after the adjectives expressing irritation, touchiness, annoyance (fractious, nettlesome, peevish, petulant, testy, tetchy, irritable, cross, grumpy, huffy, touchy, feisty)?

For example: huffy (grumpy, peevish) about somebody/something *but* irascible (irritable, cross) with... *and* mad at/with...

Comment: Most of your adjectives normally describe *inherent, permanent* dispositions / personality traits, so they don't often occur in contexts requiring a preposition to link some *specific cause* of the mental state (as a *reaction* to something). *Some* of your adjectives often occur in conjunction with a specific "irritant", so you'll often hear things like *He's touchy **about** his baldness*, but you won't often hear a word like ***feisty*** prepositionally linked to some situation or person who *causes* the subject to be like that.

Comment: ...also note that you can be ***cross about / at / with** [someone or something]*. Sometimes it makes no real difference which preposition you use, but the exact context may affect your choice. For example, *I'm cross **about** my son, who failed his exam* might *actually* imply I'm annoyed at the teachers or examiners for doing a bad job (my son being a *victim* of "injustice"; he *should* have passed) - but *I'm cross **at / with** my son, who failed his exam* unambiguously asserts that *my son himself* is the object of my ire.

Comment: If you search this site for "angry at" you'll find variations on this question.

Answer (score 1):

Prepositions are one of the hardest parts of English grammar. They don't conform to a logical, consistent system and they vary widely by dialect. So there's no fail-safe option but to absorb them through usage. In general, though, in standard American English:

- **About** and sometimes **over** are used for an action or something intangible. You're mad/angry *about* the way she treated them. You're upset *about* his dismissive attitude. (With "upset," but not "mad" or "angry," you can use *over* in these contexts. Your upset *over* your experience at the DMV.)
- **At** and sometimes **with** are used for people. You're mad/angry *at* him. You're upset *at* her. (Again, upset is a little different, and you can be upset *with* someone. You can be angry *with* them too, but being mad *with* them is non-standard. Of course, to be mad *for* someone is to be in love with them. Prepositions are hard.)